# SQL-design issue - Ordering worker for work teams on a weekly basis

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I'm making a web solution using ASP.net MVC6 and Azure SQL-db.

My goal is to make an order system for ordering work teams on a  weekly basis and it must be possible to display the work order 6 weeks ahead from todays date. Each work order is connected to a project. A manager should be able to choose a project and then start ordering different kinds of workers (disiplin), assign his need for manpower for each disiplin for 6 weeks ahead. A disiplin can be carpenter, painter, bricklayer etc.

Each project can have any number of disiplin assigned so it's not possible to hard code this  into the table structur. You can hardcode the week either as week 2 in 2016 is different from week 2 in 2017

A workorder can look like this:

```
Project A

Disiplin  |   Week 1  |  Week 2  |  Week 3  |  Week 4  |  Week 5  |  Week 6  
Carpenter |    4      |    3     |    0     |    0     |    3     |    0
Painter   |    0      |    0     |    2     |    3     |    3     |    3
```

Next project can look like this:

```
Project B

Disiplin  |   Week 44 |  Week 45 |  Week 46 |  Week 47 |  Week 48 |  Week 49  
Carpenter |    4      |    3     |    0     |    0     |    3     |    0
Painter   |    0      |    0     |    2     |    3     |    3     |    3   
Bricklayer|    1      |    2     |    1     |    5     |    3     |    0
Carpentry |    4      |    3     |    0     |    0     |    3     |    0
```

As you see the week number and number of disiplin may vary from project to project. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to design the SQL-tables to efficently store these values.

Can anyone review this issue and point me in the right direction? Thanks.

EDIT:

The problem is really not to store data but how to query for them. You never know for how many weeks each disiplin has registered data and you don't know how many disiplins registered on each project. In addition for week 2 you may have registered the manpower-needs for Carpenters but not for Painters. I could make a query for each disipline, but I would preferably have one query to get the complete grid.

Comment: This might seem rude, but it really isn't meant to be. You shouldn't be designing the schema at all.  Poor DB designs can lead to a lot of problems down the road.  Leave the DB creation and design to an experienced DBA and focus on transferring the proper business req. to him or her instead.

Comment: Well, that wasn't helpful and you are condescending. I don't think you realise the complexity of the situation. The problem seems straight forward at first and one ID per cell seems like the obvious solution, but it creates a heck of a job in a CRUD-scenario. When a manager works with this form he sees a grid with week columns and disiplin rows and when he saves it each week/disiplin cell needs to do a CRUD-action. Some cells must be updated, some cells stays the same and some cells need to be inserted. My question is, is this the most efficient way to solve this?